# Call Artisan Commands via Code NOT Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## Description

In my Laravel application, I run

```
php artisan languages:export
```

I got a `csv` file to export successfully base on my `languages` table.

BUT the goal is to leverage this [Artisan::call](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan) from Laravel, but when I did this in my code

```
$export = Artisan::call('languages:export');
```

---

## Result

I kept getting `0` as my result of `$export` variable - *no file exported of course*.

---

## Update

Now I try to call it via `shell_exec() and exec()`

```
$cmd = 'php '.base_path().'/artisan languages:export';
$export = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I see nothing generated on either one.

From the command line interface, I run

> php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/artisan languages:export

I saw my csv file generated.

---

**How would one go about and call artisan commands via code ?**

Comment: Per the API docs, the result of `Artisan::call` is an int. I suspect it's an exit code, and that zero (as with a bash script) indicates successful completion.

Comment: @ceejayoz : Thanks for your elaboration and correcting my thoughts.

Comment: I'm still very curious why it only work if I run the artisan command via command line, but not inside the code.

Comment: `Artisan::call` and `php artisan <command>` are not identical behind-the-scenes. They do similar things, but are intended to be used in different ways, and accordingly, act differently.

Comment: @ihue does the user that you run the `Artisan::call` command through your application has the rights to create and write to that csv file location? It sounds like a permissions problem to me. Did you try to create a custom artisan command creating a single file to test this?

Comment: Can you show us the command `languages:export` implementation class? since there is many laravel packages uses the `App::runningInConsole` check statement. [app()->runningInConsole()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e53a81a2bf406f501cdf818ad949f8d6c8dabfc0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L526).

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098424/3584881)

Answer (score 9):

Try to check output by calling 
`dd(Artisan::output());` 
after 
`$export = Artisan::call('languages:export');`

Comment: Ok. I can try that.

Comment: Artisan::output() gives exact output as cli, you saved my day!!! thanks

Answer (score 8):

Your console command isn't going to return the CSV file that way, because that's not how console commands work. The fact that you're getting `0` is actually a good thing console land (it means it completed without throwing errors).

Your call is correct, it's your expectation that is wrong. You'll need to change your approach for however you're consuming `$export`. If you want to actually access the newly-created CSV, have a look at the `phpleague/csv` package and/or the built in `fopen` command. If you just want to know that it completed successfully, then just take that `0` as a success.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my thought, and expectation. But I still have 1 doubt. Why do I need to look into phpleague/csv ? my code already did that. I already know how to do that. It work when I run this **php artisan languages:export** on my CLI, it only does NOT work when I run it from the code. It has nothing to with the way I export file.

Comment: I only mention it because it's a good tool to read and write CSV files.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function with `php artisan languages:export` as parameter. You may need to include the right path in front of the command in that case.

I've also found the function [`Artisan::command`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan) instead of call, maybe that works?

Comment: I can try that but the actual goal is to make it work with Laravel `Artisan::call` ...

Comment: See my update, I tried it, and it doesn't seem to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Artisan:call() support $outputBuffer parameter, do you try it?

```
$parameters = [];
$outputBuffer = null;
Artisan::call('languages:export', $parameters, $outputBuffer);
```